# How can I send a file using AWS S3 API conding in java? My error is: The Content-MD5 you specified is not valid

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I can send files without problem using Postman but when try send it in java it doesn't work.

I've tried everything, but always when try send a file with Content I receive this Error Message : The Content-MD5 you specified is not valid.

When I said, "with Content" I mean for example a text file named "text.txt" with "test 123". But when I tried send the same file but without content it's works fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBaEk.png)
Error messagem:
`{"Error": { "Message": "The Content-MD5 you specified is not valid.", "RequestId": 822352709, "Resource": "/dns1niadf001/textoSemConteudo.txt", "Code": "InvalidDigest" }}`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Is "test 123" the MD5 value you are attempting to send along with the file content?  It is very unlikely that "test 123" is the MD5 value of the file.  It sounds to me like S3 is expecting the MD5 value you send with your content to match the MD5 value it is calculating on the AWS side.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried convert it to MD5 and send but doesn't work. A friend send me a solution using chunk connection and now it's working fine.

Comment: @FabianodeSouza can you share the solution you used? I'm having the same issue but with .net sdk, but i guess it would be something similar what we are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the .NET AWSSDK.S3. The key was that when using PutObjectRequest object, there is a default value in the property UseChunkEncoding=true. Well, if you set that value to false everything will work fine.